# Viewer v7.37 Property Panel setProperties() Not Work

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Viewer V7 7.37 PropertyPanle.setProperties() can not be loaded.

```
let promise1 = this.viewer.getExtensionAsync("Autodesk.PropertiesManager");
promise1.then(function (propertiesManagerEx) {
    let panel1 = propertiesManagerEx.getPanel();
    panel1.setProperties = function (properties, options) {
      ...
```

Does this have any effect?
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/
7.37
Release Date: 2/18/2021
Property panel: support multi-selection

Comment: By "cannot be loaded", what do you mean? Is it throwing an error you can share with us?

Comment: Thank you very much.

Before Ver7.37,
When I click a item for Property Panel to show the Properties,
It will call this function(panel1.setProperties = function (properties, options)) to do my custom setting.

At Ver7.37,
When I click a item to show it,
this function can not be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your observation is correct. Now the **setAggregatedProperties** function is called. You can check in the source code as well: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.37/viewer3D.js

In order to avoid any issues, the best thing is to always specify the Viewer version your app is working with:
https://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/07/always-use-versioning.html
(this is a very old article so the Viewer's URLs changed since then)